# LoadBalancer in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, minikube

I have installed kubernetes using minikube on a single node. I have implemented ‘LoadBalancer’ type of service which manages 3 pods. By default, it uses a ‘network load balancer’. Can we change load balancer type in service .yaml file or can we change load balancer algorithm used? please find the service file below :

— myservice.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo-apps-lb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    port: 80
  selector:
      app: app1
```

Note : Here I am not using any cloud platform, all the things are on single host machine.

Comment: You can use `Nodeport` type to expose your service on a specific port. The port should be in between 30000-32676 ports. After using nodeport service type you would be able to access your service at http://<vm_ip>:<node_port>

Answer (score 1):

If you have later plan to attach domain do DNS mapping check this indirectly this will also make load balancer but handling request and other stuff is easy with it.

> https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

You can use annotation to change load balancer type.

> service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type

Answer (score 0):

If you use load balancer type service on cloud , cloud provider will create load balancer for you and update that information in this service.

You can use below annotation to change load balancer type and it is only supported on aws only.

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type
```

Answer (score 0):

Because use are using minikube, I think it is safe to assume that this is for development environment. You always have the option to change the way a service is exposed. See [kubernetes docs in service types section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).

Now when you want to mimic the production in your dev env on the types of services, you have varied work arounds for this. Now because Minikube doesn't come bundled with LoadBalancer, you have to either install one (like [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/)) in here or try workarounds/hacks as detailed in the [blog post](https://blog.codonomics.com/2019/02/loadbalancer-support-with-minikube-for-k8s.html).

Hope that helps!